# Visibility of element - visible but not to a webdriver, too

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have three dropdowns, first is by default open, second and third are closed.
For a first it works OK, (actually I open first dropdown, choose first match from list, open it and navigate back) but for a second - dropdown is closed by default and when I open that dropdown and try to click on first element - got error **Element is not visible.** 
Code which I tried with is:

```
// Default status of 'Live Matches' dropdown is closed
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='medium-12 column padding-reset']/div/div/div/div[2]/h3")).click();
```

Opened dropdown correctly, but after that got error: **Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:** for code below:enter image description here

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"0\"]/a/div/h2/div[1]"))).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
```

Also, added screenshots of which element I am looking and path when inspected. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Just as a **Note**: this is same situation as described in Question [Why Selenium can't find an element that is graphically visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721143/why-selenium-cant-find-an-element-that-is-graphically-visible?rq=1) and not answered

Comment: If you are using a public URL, please provide the URL. Because, the same code is working for me in some [URL](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#!)

Comment: @Sridhar Unfortunately, URL is not public

Comment: @Sridhar - You wrote that it works on **some** URL, why not at any URL?

Comment: That's why I asked about the URL may be it has something related to page source, which may make it invisible at the time of action. Also, you can upgrade to selenium 3.0.x instead of 2.xx.x and check whether it is any API issue with selenium, which may be fixed on next iterations.

Comment: @Sridhar Could you be so kind to explain what could cause invisibility and I will search on page source. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you make a static page which can be served with jsfiddle, with just the dropbox in the code, so that we can try to test it with selenium.